# How to find zeros of this strange function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $Z_q = e^{\frac{2 \pi\mathbf i}{q}}$, $1 \ne q \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^{q-1} \dfrac{1}{1-{Z_q}^i}$ is never zero? If not how to find zeros of this sum?

If we factor $1/(1-Z_q)$ from each term, $1/(1-Z_q)$ is not zero, for sure.

But, how would you prove that  $1+1/(1+Z_q)+1/(1+Z_q+Z_q^2)  + \cdots   + 1/(1+Z_q+Z_q^2+..+ Z_q^{q-2})$ is not  zero?

Comment: There are tags `polynomials`  and `roots`, and an answer that mentions polynomials, but I don't see any of them in the question, just some complex numbers. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Marc can you think of a polynomial that $Z_q$ satisfies?

Comment: @Empy2 No, polynomials are impossible to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac1{1-x}\\x=1-\frac1y$$
You know what polynomial $x$ is a root of, so you can work out what polynomial $y$ is a root of.
Then you can work out the sum of the roots of the second one.

Comment: What polynomial?

Comment: Well, what sum is OP trying to find?

Comment: A sum of $q-1$ complex numbers. No polynomials there.

Comment: Sometimes, knowledge of polynomials gives a way to find a sum

Comment: Maybe if you wrote "is a root of" instead of "satisfies", or alternatively "polynomial equation" instead of "polynomial" (twice), your sentence would be easier to decipher.

Comment: Ah.  I was wondering what your point was.